# Why are journald logs in different order than shell output?

Tags: python, systemd, journalctl

I'm running the following Python script with `./test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import snowboydecoder
import sys
import signal
import speech_recognition as sr
import cec
import os

"""
This demo file shows you how to use the new_message_callback to interact with
the recorded audio after a keyword is spoken. It uses the speech recognition
library in order to convert the recorded audio into text.

Information on installing the speech recognition library can be found at:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/
"""

interrupted = False

def audioRecorderCallback(fname):
    print("converting audio to text")
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    f = open("key.json")
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    with sr.AudioFile(fname) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        print(r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, key, "hu-HU"))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    os.remove(fname)



def detectedCallback():
  print('recording audio...', end='', flush=True)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True


def interrupt_callback():
    global interrupted
    return interrupted

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("Unspecified model, defaulting to snowboy.umdl")
    print("Usage: test.py your.model")
    model = "/mnt/samba/shared/snowboy/snowboy.umdl"
else:
    model = sys.argv[1]

cec.init()
cec_devices = cec.list_devices()

# capture SIGINT signal, e.g., Ctrl+C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

detector = snowboydecoder.HotwordDetector(model, sensitivity=0.7, audio_gain=1)
print('Listening... Press Ctrl+C to exit')

# main loop
detector.start(detected_callback=detectedCallback,
               audio_recorder_callback=audioRecorderCallback,
               silent_count_threshold=4,
               recording_timeout=10,
               interrupt_check=interrupt_callback,
               sleep_time=0.01)

detector.terminate()
```

The output is largely what I expect; items that look like this [[[is my comment]]]:

```
Unspecified model, defaulting to snowboy.umdl
Usage: test.py your.model
Listening... Press Ctrl+C to exit
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[[[Program waits here for verbal input]]]
INFO:snowboy:Keyword 1 detected at time: 2020-12-02 12:09:45
recording audio...converting audio to text
[[[Likely unrelated googleapi timeout error]]]
```

However, when I turn the script into a systemd script with `/etc/systemd/system/test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Super user test service
After=sound.target network.target
Requires=sound.target
Wants=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/snowboy
ExecStart=/mnt/samba/shared/snowboy/test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get an unexplicably different output from `journalctl -u test.service -f`

```
Dec 02 12:00:59 ARPI systemd[1]: Started Super user test service.
Dec 02 12:01:08 ARPI test.py[25846]: Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
[[[Identical ALSA lib messages]]]
Dec 02 12:01:08 ARPI test.py[25846]: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[[[Program waits here for verbal input]]]
Dec 02 12:04:47 ARPI test.py[25846]: INFO:snowboy:Keyword 1 detected at time: 2020-12-02 12:04:47
Dec 02 12:04:47 ARPI test.py[25846]: Unspecified model, defaulting to snowboy.umdl
Dec 02 12:04:47 ARPI test.py[25846]: Usage: test.py your.model
Dec 02 12:04:47 ARPI test.py[25846]: Listening... Press Ctrl+C to exit
Dec 02 12:05:49 ARPI test.py[25846]: recording audio...WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Sleeping 1.39 seconds before retry 1 of 1 for request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/speech/v1/rest, after timed out
Dec 02 12:06:51 ARPI test.py[25846]: converting audio to text
[[[Likely unrelated googleapi timeout error]]]
Dec 02 12:06:51 ARPI systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 12:06:51 ARPI systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 02 12:06:52 ARPI systemd[1]: test.service: Service RestartSec=1s expired, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 12:06:52 ARPI systemd[1]: test.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Dec 02 12:06:52 ARPI systemd[1]: Stopped Super user test service.
```

I tried `sudo journalctl --sync` while the service was waiting for input, but the lines I expected (Unspecified model, listening, yada-yada...) did not appear in the journal.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually stdout, and not stdout + stderr intermixed?

Comment: I belive both stderr and stdout is logged to the journal, yes. My main problem was that some lines didn't appear in the journal at the point they did in shell. This made debugging hard, becuase I had to trigger the hotword to see the complete output (and in the case of the actual project, even then it didn't display some important messages from a callback it turns out), which was really time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this writeup](https://milosophical.me/blog/2018/journald-experiments-0.html) about `journald`, which pointed out there might be problems with buffering.

It lead me to [this Python specific Unix StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164987/output-of-a-python-script-running-as-unit-is-out-of-order-while-shells-seems-unn) with a solution.

Adding `Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"` under `[Service]` in the systemd service file solved the problem.

Comment: Great self-solved question!